# Não consigo fazer divisão com um elemento de vetor

Tags: c, array, matemática

Fiz um código para simular o paradoxo de Monty Hall, de modo que eu possa simular 1000 vezes os resultados e escrever as estatísticas. Porém não consigo dividir um elemento de um 'array' de 'int' por um 'int', todas as vezes que executo o programa, ao chegar na divisão, o programa trava e tem que ser fechado:

```
void main(){
    int PORTAS [] = {0, 0, 0}; 
    int CAR, ESC, NUM, DECISAO, AUX;
    float VIT, DER; 
    int ESTAT [] = {0, 0, 0};   // {Tentativas, vitórias, derrotas}

    VIT = ( ESTAT[2] / NUM ) * 100; // Porcentagem de vitórias  *ERRO*
    DER = ( ESTAT[3] / NUM ) * 100; // Porcentagem de derrotas  *ERRO*
}
```

Tentei também escrever como:

```
VIT = ESTAT[2]/ESTAT[1]*100;
DER = ESTAT[3]/ESTAT[1]*100;
```

Porém deste modo, o resultado dá sempre 0.

Se necessário para me ajudarem, vou colocar o código completo, que inclui no início uma breve explicação do jogo. Se julgarem que não é preciso, ignorem o código abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>

/*Paradoxo de Monty Hall
*Atrás de uma porta, de três no total, é escondido um carro
*e nas outras duas, uma cabra. No jogo, o jogador escolhe uma
*porta e então é revelada outra porta que contenha uma cabra.
*O jogador tem então a opção de escolher entre manter a escolha
*ou trocar de porta. Esse programa simula esse jogo, de modo que 
*a porta seja mantida ou trocada em todas as tentativas, para
*motivos estatísticos.*/

void main(){
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "");

    int PORTAS [] = {0, 0, 0};  // 0 - a porta contém uma cabra; 1 - a porta contém o carro 
    int CAR, ESC, NUM, DECISAO, AUX;
    float VIT, DER; 
    int ESTAT [] = {0, 0, 0};   // {Tentativas, vitórias, derrotas}

    printf("1 para trocar todas, 0 para manter todas: ");
    scanf ("%d", &DECISAO);
    printf ("Digite o número de repetições: "); // Recomendável 10, 100 ou 1000.
    scanf ("%d", &NUM);

    do{
        CAR = rand () %3;   // Randomiza a porta que recebe o carro.
        PORTAS [CAR] = 1;   

        ESC = rand () %3;   // Randomiza a escolha da porta.

        if ( DECISAO == 1 ){    // Se foi escolhido trocar todas as vezes.
            if ( PORTAS [ESC] == 1 ){   // Porta escolhida contém o carro.
                for ( AUX = 0; AUX < 3 ; AUX++ ){
                    if ( PORTAS [AUX] != 1 && AUX != ESC ){
                        ESC = AUX;      //Mudança de porta
                        AUX = 3;    // Para quebrar o 'For'
                        ESTAT [3] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ( PORTAS [ESC] == 0){    //Porta escolhida contém uma cabra.
                ESC = CAR;  // Pois sendo a porta errada, e tendo a outra errada sido revelada, só sobrou a correta.
                ESTAT [2] += 1;
            }
        }

        if ( DECISAO == 0){     //Caso tenha sido escolhido manter todas as vezes.
            if ( ESC = CAR ){
                ESTAT [2] += 1;
            }
            else{
                ESTAT [3] += 1;
            }
        }

        NUM--;
        ESTAT [1] += 1;
    } while ( NUM > 0);

    VIT = ( ESTAT[2] / NUM ) * 100; // Porcentagem de vitórias  *ERRO*
    DER = ( ESTAT[3] / NUM ) * 100; // Porcentagem de derrotas  *ERRO*

    ( DECISAO == 1 ) ? printf ("\n\n\n\tTrocando de porta todas as vezes: \n\n") : printf ("\n\n\n\tMantendo a porta todas as vezes: \n\n");
    printf ("Número de tentativas: %d\n", ESTAT [1]);
    printf ("Número de vitórias: %d, %d%% do total.\n", ESTAT [2], VIT);
    printf ("Número de derrotas: %d, %d%% do total.", ESTAT [3], DER);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: E qual é o problema? Está dando erro de divisão por 0?

Comment: Esqueci de incluir o erro, foi mal. Do primeiro modo, o programa simplesmente trava, e do segundo, o resultado dá sempre 0. Vou incluir na pergunta.

Comment: Inicializas todos os elementos de `PORTAS` com `0` e depois, dentro do loop, vais la metendo `1` ... mas nunca voltas a por `0` e portanto atras de cada porta acaba por estar sempre um carro. Oh! e deixa de usar maisculas!

Comment: Obrigado, não havia notado isso. E não é recomendável usar maiúsculas? Comecei a usar porque eu achei melhor para identificar visualmente as variáveis.

Comment: @DouglasMarques Normalmente convenciona-se que `minusculas` são para métodos/variáveis, `MAIUSCULAS` para constantes e `PrimeirasLetrasMaiusculas` para tipos (`struct`, `typedef`, ou nas linguagens que dão suporte, classes). Você pode fugir da convenção, mas dificulta outras pessoas entenderem seu código, então eu não recomendo.

Comment: @DouglasMarques Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Note que como você declarou variáveis inteiras as operações serão feitas com matemática inteira e apenas na atribuição o resultado será convertido para real. Utilize um cast para forçar a operação em ponto flutuante.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei qual é o objetivo mas isto é matemática básica. O código está sendo executado quando `NUM` vale 0 e esta operação não é possível de acordo com a regra matemática.

Provavelmente não deveria usar um *array* para este problema específico da pergunta, três variáveis seriam mais legíveis. Isto é só uma das coisas que torna o código difícil de ler e entender. Além disto está usando os elementos 1, 2 e 3 quando deveria ser 0, 1 e 2.

A segunda forma pode não causar o problema mas é o que deseja? Não pode ficar incluindo variáveis aleatórias na expressão para ver se dá certo. E esta usada é bem aleatória, não faz o menor sentido. Tem que fazer o que precisa. E só você sabe disto.

Eu acho que deveria ser como na primeira forma, mas mantendo o valor inicial da variável. Não pode reaproveitar variáveis. Eu criei uma variável nova chamada `repeticoes` para guardar o valor e fazer a divisão corretamente.

Na verdade o código está cheio de erros. Não adianta tentar resolver problemas complexos quando não se sabe o básico da programação. Depois de resolver vários erros de compilação parece que deu certo, mas não garanto que está fazendo o desejado. Portanto deve haver problemas que vão além do que está na pergunta.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int PORTAS[] = {0, 0, 0};  // 0 - a porta contém uma cabra; 1 - a porta contém o carro 
    int ESTAT[] = {0, 0, 0};   // {Tentativas, vitórias, derrotas}
    int repeticoes;
    int DECISAO;
    printf("1 para trocar todas, 0 para manter todas: ");
    scanf ("%d", &DECISAO);
    printf ("Digite o número de repetições: "); // Recomendável 10, 100 ou 1000.
    scanf ("%d", &repeticoes);
    int NUM = repeticoes;
    do {
        int AUX;
        int CAR = rand () %3;   // Randomiza a porta que recebe o carro.
        PORTAS[CAR] = 1;   
        int ESC = rand () %3;   // Randomiza a escolha da porta.
        if (DECISAO == 1) {    // Se foi escolhido trocar todas as vezes.
            if (PORTAS[ESC] == 1 ) {   // Porta escolhida contém o carro.
                for (AUX = 0; AUX < 3 ; AUX++) {
                    if (PORTAS[AUX] != 1 && AUX != ESC) {
                        ESC = AUX;      //Mudança de porta
                        AUX = 3;    // Para quebrar o 'For'
                        ESTAT[2] += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (PORTAS[ESC] == 0) {    //Porta escolhida contém uma cabra.
                ESC = CAR;  // Pois sendo a porta errada, e tendo a outra errada sido revelada, só sobrou a correta.
                ESTAT[1] += 1;
            }
        }
        if (DECISAO == 0) {     //Caso tenha sido escolhido manter todas as vezes.
            if (ESC == CAR ) ESTAT[1] += 1;
            else  ESTAT[2] += 1;
        }
        NUM--;
        ESTAT[0] += 1;
    } while (NUM > 0);
    float VIT = (ESTAT[2] / repeticoes) * 100; // Porcentagem de vitórias  *ERRO*
    float DER = (ESTAT[3] / repeticoes) * 100; // Porcentagem de derrotas  *ERRO*
    (DECISAO == 1) ? printf("\n\n\n\tTrocando de porta todas as vezes: \n\n") : printf("\n\n\n\tMantendo a porta todas as vezes: \n\n");
    printf("Número de tentativas: %d\n", ESTAT[0]);
    printf("Número de vitórias: %d, %f%% do total.\n", ESTAT[1], VIT);
    printf("Número de derrotas: %d, %f%% do total.", ESTAT[2], DER);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5z3qbx). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/DivisionInArrayc). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/DivisionInArray.c).

Melhorei o código mas não tudo.

Comment: Realmente, não notei que o NUM estava com 0 no final.  Quanto a segunda forma, não são aleatórias, o primeiro elemento do array ESTAT é a contagem de repetições, o segundo e o número de vitórias, então o segundo sobre o primeiro é a fração que indica as vitórias, por exemplo. Quanto aos outros erros, por favor, me indique. A única parte que deu errada foi essa na minha compilação, o resto saiu exatamente como desejado. E realmente, cometo sim muitos erros básicos, porque não é minha área e comecei a estudar há algumas semanas apenas.

Comment: Pode ser, mas o código está tão confuso que não dá para entender isto. Como eu falei, este *array* nem deveria existir, pode parecer que há uma relação entre elas, mas no fundo são 4 informações distintas. Eu consertei os erros, basta analisar o meu código. Primeiro precisa assentar tijolo pra depois tentar construir uma casa. Acredite, isto nunca dá certo.

Comment: Sobraram poucos erros na versão modificada: 1) as portas nunca são resetadas pra 0, então eventualmente todas conterão o carro; 2) o primeiro `if` é desnecessariamente complexo, se a porta contém o carro e o jogador escolheu trocar, ele vai perder, não precisa desse loop pra saber isso (mas apesar disso ele parece estar correto, então não mexi); 3) faltou um else depois desse if; 4) na hora de fazer as estatísticas, a divisão foi inteira, por isso deu sempre zero. [exemplo modificado funcionando como esperado](http://ideone.com/XXsZe9)

Comment: P.S. Pessoalmente não achei o código tão confuso assim, achei até bem fácil de entender considerando que foi escrito por um iniciante (exceto por aquele loop desnecessário envolvendo `AUX`). Por outro lado, eu já tinha conhecimento prévio do Monty Hall, então eu já sabia o que esperar, se fosse um domínio desconhecido não sei se minha impressão seria a mesma ou não...

Comment: @mgibsonbr é confuso de ler e acompanhar por dar nomes ruins. Não é complexo, só mal escrito.

Answer (score 0):

> Tentei também escrever como:
>
> ```
> VIT = ESTAT[2]/ESTAT[1]*100;
> DER = ESTAT[3]/ESTAT[1]*100;
> ```

Há dois problemas aqui: primeiro, em C os *arrays* são indexados a partir do zero, não do um, de modo que o primeiro elemento tem índice `0`, o segundo índice `1` e o terceiro índice `2`. Acessar o índice `3` como você está fazendo é inválido para um *array* de tamanho `3`, e o resultado é indefinido (pois você está acessando uma região de memória arbitrária, que pode até estar fora do escopo do seu programa).

O segundo problema é que a divisão inteira sempre dará um resultado inteiro, ainda que a variável onde você pretenda armazenar o resultado seja `float`. Se o dividendo for menor que o divisor então, o resultado será sempre zero (como você observou). Corrigindo ambos os problemas temos:

```
 VIT = 1.0f*ESTAT[1]/ESTAT[0]*100; // Ao multiplicar primeiro por 1.0f
 DER = 1.0f*ESTAT[2]/ESTAT[0]*100; // o operando passa a ser um float
```

Já sua primeira tentativa (como `NUM`) era falha porque você esteve decrementando `NUM` no seu *loop* até chegar a zero. Ao tentar dividir por zero, naturalmente haveria um problema...

P.S. Não revisei o código completo - pois [o Maniero já fez isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100181/215) - mas após a correção dos principais erros chegamos a [esse resultado final](http://ideone.com/XXsZe9) (cujo resultado corresponde ao esperado, estatisticamente falando). Algumas recomendações:

- Não use variáveis com o nome todo em maiúsculas, pois essa notação é tradicionalmente usada para representar constantes apenas;
- Documente suas variáveis, e procure dar-lhes nomes auto-descritivos. Eu pessoalmente não tive dificuldade de entender o que era `CAR`[ro] e `ESC`[olha], mas isso se deve ao conhecimento prévio que eu tinha do Monty Hall, outras pessoas podem ter mais dificuldade de relacionar as variáveis aos elementos do domínio;
- Se duas condições se excluem mutuamente, eu sugiro usar `else` mesmo que você ache que não seja necessário. Nesse código:

  ```
      if ( PORTAS [ESC] == 1 ){   // Porta escolhida contém o carro.
         ...
      }

      if ( PORTAS [ESC] == 0){    //Porta escolhida contém uma cabra.
         ...
      }
  ```

  você não usou o `else`, e por isso ele acabou entrando no segundo `if` mesmo depois de ter entrado no primeiro (pois este modificava `ESC`) - fazendo com que o número de acertos mais o número de erros superasse o número de tentativas...

  Dois `if`s seguidos sem `else` só devem ser usados se existe a chance de entrar: a) só no primeiro; b) só no segundo; c) em ambos; d) em nenhum dos dois.
- Eu vi que você tentou simular a mudança de escolha (reatribuindo `ESC`), mas nesse caso isso é desnecessário - se ele escolheu certo, vai perder, se escolheu errado, vai ganhar, não é necessário simular mais nada. De todo modo, seu *loop* que usa `AUX` está correto, ainda que meio confuso (a propósito, você sabia que pode sair mais cedo de um *loop* usando `break`?).